# See the last times I logged in on Linux?

Tags: linux, macos, ubuntu, command-line, unix

I want to see my previous logins when I login using the command line in Ubuntu 10 and I am wondering if there is a command to do it?

The command should show the last times/dates that I logged in.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `last` command shows all previous and active logins. `last $USER` restricts to your user. `last $USER | head -n 3` shows the latest 3.

The list of previous logins is reinitialized every month by default, and a copy of the previous month is kept (you can interrogate it with `last -f /var/log/wtmp.1`). This is controlled in `/etc/logrotate.conf`.

Comment: Thanks Gilles. I tested and it works on `Mac OS X` and `Ubuntu`. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Try with `last`. See `man last` for the options.